# Playstation 4 controller d-pad jammed.

Tags: controllers, ps4

I play the new "Mortal Kombat X" game on the ps4 and I use the d-pad to play because using the analog stick is really hard, and now on one of my controllers the left button is jammed and is permanently pressed and on the other controller, the buttons are not precise when pressed. Pressing the left button sometimes hits like down-left at the same time and stuff like that. Is either controller fixable or is it time to get a new one?

Comment: Why don't you take apart the controller following a guide like [This](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/DualShock_4) and repair the d-pad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning the controller. A "Compressed Air Duster Can" (usually used to clean computer keyboards) could be useful in removing any dirt from around the buttons and D-pad.

You can also use a toothpick or similar thin (but not sharp item), to clean the crevices of the controller to help remove any dirt or grime stick in the hard to reach places.

If either of the above fail, you can try returning the controller (if it's within warranty of 1 year) and try and get a replacement. The worst case scenario is that you may need to buy a new controller.